# Quicker way to take a power of a permutation in cycles?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

**Q:** Let $f$ be a permutation on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, defined as follows $$f=(576)(642835).$$
Write the permutation $f^4$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

---

A key question that I have: is it typically better to first rewrite $f$ as a product of disjoint cycles so that taking powers will then be easy:
$$f=(576)(642835)=(283574)\implies f^2=(283574)^2$$ Or, should simply keep them separate: $$f^2=(576)(642835)\cdot(576)(642835).$$ In the latter case, would $$f^2=(576)(642835)(576)(642835)=(576)^2(642835)^2$$ be true? Because in this instance, these 2 cycles are no longer disjoint, meaning that shouldn't be commutative right?

Meanwhile, I can write $f^2=(283574)(283574)=(237)(485)$, whereby because they are disjoint cycles, I can do $f^4=(f^2)^2=(237)^2(485)^2$.

Any feedback and/or suggestions and insight on how to tackle this question would be much appreciated. Sincerely, an absolute beginner.

Comment: You can just do it in-line. Apply $f$ once to $2$ and you get $8$.Apply it again and you get $3$. A third time and you get $5$. And a final fourth time maps $5$ to $7$ (since you are composing left to right). So &f^4$ sends $2$ to $7$.Now do it to $7$. Etc. There is no more need to fully calculate all the partial computations than there is to do the sum of four numbers by first carefully computing the sum of the first two, then the sum of that and the third, and finally the sum of *that* result with the fourth number. We just add them!

Comment: That said, to calculate very large powers, [multiplication by successive squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring?wprov=sfti1) may be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that this is effectively permuting every single element individually (vertices of a n-gon of the symmetric group?)

Answer (score 1):

(Multiplication is left-to-right, following OPs convention)

For small powers, and single calculations, just doing it "in-line" may take the least amount of work. You can simply see what happens to each term when you apply $f$ multiple times, without first re-writing $f$ as a product of disjoint cycles. With
$$f=(576)(642835)$$
you can see that $1$ is fixed. That $2$ is first mapped to $8$, then $3$, then $5$, and then $7$, so $f^4 = (27\cdots$; then $7$ is mapped to $4$, then $2$, then $8$, and then $3$, so $f^4 = (273\cdots$, etc.

However, it is easy to take a power of a cycle. To take the power $k$th power of $(a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n)$, we just get $(a_{1+k}a_{2+k}\cdots a_{n+k})$, with the indices taken modulo $n$ (so $n+1\equiv 1$, $n+2\equiv 2$, etc).

And since disjoint cycles commute, if $f=\sigma_1\cdots\sigma_r$, where the $\sigma_i$ are pairwise disjoint cycles, then $f^k = \sigma_1^k\sigma_2^k\cdots \sigma_r^k$. So if you are doing a large power, or multiple computations, then the overhead of expressing $f$ as a product of disjoint cycles first may be worth it, because it will make further calculations easier. But for instance, if you only needed to compute $f^3$, or $f^2$, then it'll take less time to just compute it directly than to first write it as a product of disjoint cycles and then computing the power.